# Cannot find org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main when launching fatjar built by wildfly-swarm-plugin:1.0.0.Alpha1

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

I've checked out https://github.com/arun-gupta/wildfly-samples/tree/master/swarm by Arun Gupta, but when trying to launch the built jar I get `Error: Could not find or load main class org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.`

```
\wildfly-samples-master\swarm>mvn clean install

[INFO] --- wildfly-swarm-plugin:1.0.0.Alpha1:create (default) @ swarm ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ swarm ---
[INFO] Installing \wildfly-samples-master\swarm\target\swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to \.m2\repository\org\wildfly\samples\swarm\swarm\1.0-SNAPSHOT\swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing \wildfly-samples-master\swarm\pom.xml to \.m2\repository\org\wildfly\samples\swarm\swarm\1.0-SNAPSHOT\swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing \wildfly-samples-master\swarm\target\swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT-swarm.jar to \.m2\repository\org\wildfly\samples\swarm\swarm\1.0-SNAPSHOT\swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT-swarm.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.115 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-26T21:06:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 49M/313M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

\wildfly-samples-master\swarm>java -jar target/swarm-1.0-SNAPSHOT-swarm.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main


\wildfly-samples-master\swarm>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: C:\tools\apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7.0_21
Java home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I do not understand what might be the problem here.

Can someone please advise?

EDIT: I have tried building my own example first but I'm getting the same problem. Referring to an existing example which fails for me was just easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue in Alpha1

that was already fixed https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm/commit/761cdf1848a8720614b20a2272983bcd4e5f3c60

Best to build it from sources until Alpha2 release is done.

Comment: Thank you.As of released version 1.0.0.Alpha2 this is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 1):

These are the official examples:
https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples

Alpha4 version (source) has:

- EJB support.
- More bug fixes.
- Static content support. (js,html,css, etc...)

And many others improvements...